# Double integral variable substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, integral-domain

> Let $(a,b)\in (0,1)$ and let $T>0$. Consider the following integral:
> $$
> \iint_{\Gamma }f(x)g(x+t)\,dt\,dx,
> $$
> where
> $
> \Gamma =\left\{ (t,x)\in (0,T)\times (0,1):t+x\in (0,1)\right\} .
> $

Let $s=x+t$, then $s\in (0,1)$ and $s-t\in (0,1)$, $t\in (0,T)$.
Am I right?
$$
\iint_{\Gamma }f(x)g(x+t)\,dt\,dx={\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min(1-x,T)}}f(x)g(t+x)\,dt\,dx={\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min(s,T)}}f(s-t)g(s)\,dt\,ds,
$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution is fine. Here is a variation with an intermediate step.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{x=0}^1}&\color{blue}{\int_{t=0}^{\min(1-x,T)}f(x)g(t+x)\,dt\,dx}\\
> &=\int_{t=0}^{\min(T,1)}\int_{x=0}^{1-t}f(x)g(t+x)\,dx\,dt\tag{1}\\
> &=\int_{t=0}^{\min{(T,1)}}\int_{s=t}^{1}f(s-t)g(s)\,ds\,dt\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\int_{s=0}^{1}\int_{t=0}^{\min{(s,T)}}f(s-t)g(s)\,dt\,ds}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with OPs calculation.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of integration.
- In (2) we substitute $s=x+t, ds=dx$ and set upper and lower limit of the integral accordingly.
- In (3) we change the order of integration once more.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @Gustave: You're welcome! You might want to upvote and/or accept this answer if you find it helpful.